# How to migrate to swift 4 if i can't compile because of cryptoswift?

Tags: swift, xcode, migrate

I need to compile my code but xcode can't migrate to swift 4 because it can't compile in swift 3 but Cryptoswift framework don't want to compile because it need to be in swift 4. I can compile on another computer in xcode 8.3.3 but can't upload on store in that version. What can i do?

i made the project on xcode 8.3.3 and it work well but when i tried on newer xcode, it don't and give me some error.

I expect to send the app on store in swift 3 or swift 4.

[error while migrating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNsJ7.png)
[Cryptoswift error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KBYC.png)

Comment: You should use a framework that supports at least Swift 4.

Comment: when i update it with cocoapod, i have other error. there are framework who support swift 3 and 4?

Comment: What other error? [edit] your question with that error.

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods?

Comment: CryptoSwift is compatible Swift 5: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/releases

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select the supported swift version:

[image]